# Am I checking incompressibility of a velocity flow correctly?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

My velocity flow is defined by $u_r$, $u_{\theta}$, $u_x$. This makes the strain rate tensor of the velocity flow equal to:

$J_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix} u_{rr} & u_{r\theta} & u_{rx} \\
u_{\theta r} & u_{\theta \theta} & u_{\theta x} \\
u_{xr} & u_{x\theta} & u_{xx} \end{bmatrix}$

Where $J$ can be split into a symmetrical part $\mathcal{D}$ and a anti symmetrical part $\Omega$ which are defined as:

$\mathcal{D_{ij}} = \frac{1}{2} (u_{ij} + u_{ji}), \quad \mathcal{D}^T = \mathcal{D}\\
\Omega_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} (u_{ij} - u_{ji}), \quad \Omega^T = - \Omega$

I now have to check whether or not the flow field is incompressible. And to me it seems that compressibility is defined by the diagonal terms in $J$, and vorticity is described by the off diagonal terms in $J$. Am I right when I say the following thing:

$\mathcal{D_{ij}} = \frac{1}{2} (u_{ij} + u_{ji}), \quad \mathcal{D}^T = \mathcal{D} \equiv \frac{1}{2}(2\cdot u_{rr} + 2\cdot u_{\theta \theta} + 2\cdot u_{xx})$

And that if I show that this equation is equal to zero the fluid flow is incompressible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuity equation in cylindrical coordinates is $$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial (ur)}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}=0$$

Comment: OK so I basically got the approach right but I should have used the equation for cylindrical coordinates. That's fair enough, I'll make sure I get that right.

Comment: Yes.  The Trace of the rate of deformation tensor (i.e., the double dot product of the rate of deformation tensor with the identity tensor) set equal to zero is the condition for incompressibility.

Comment: In the end I was able to prove that I was dealing with an incompressible fluid. Which makes sense, because that is mostly what my course if about.  So this solves it then!